# Cassandra insert 1020000 records take a lot of time - then crashing with write timeout during write query at consistency ONE (0 replica(s)

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I'm trying to insert 1020000 records with multiple columns
(column physical size my varies several of them are blobs).

my cluster setup:
2 nodes
using:

```
create keyspace myks with replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':2};
```

while trying to insert this data using c# client:

> I get Cassandra.WriteTimeoutException

-

Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (0 replica(s) acknowledged the write over 1 required)

while trying to retrieving data from console I've got an error:

> errors={}, last_host=192.168.180.93

any suggestions?

my schema is:

```
create table my_table(
id bigint, 
seqid int, 
activeeventtime int,
eventtime int,
eventtype text,
width int,
height int,
x int,
y int,
buttonstatetype text,
eventtype text,
statetype text,
eid int,
directiontype text,
gdistance int,
griddeclaration boolean,
pathdeclaration boolean,
child blob,
mpath blob,
primary key(id, seqid ))
```

some code snippet of how i'm trying to insert the data:

```
for (long i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < enericEvents.Count;++)
    {
       GenericSessionEvent currEvent = genericEvents[j];
       ser1.Serialize(stream1, currEvent.Child); ser2.Serialize(stream2,    
       currEvent.Element); 
       BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.Bind
      (i, j, ....stream1.GetBuffer(), stream2.GetBuffer());
      await session.ExecuteAsync(boundStatement); 
    }
}
```

what I see in the logs that seems strange is:

```
WARN [CompactionExecuter:13]... BigTableWriter.java:184 - Writing large 
partition ...tableNAme (107865330 bytes).
```

I want also to mention that it crashed ~ when i variable value is about 30.
but it takes several minutes to reach there also.
after that is crashed.

Comment: How many nodes in your ring ? How many client do you use ? What does nodetool status say ? Are there any exception in the cassandra.log files or anoraml GC activity or StatusLogger ?

Comment: I have 2 nodes in the ring. nodetool status says "UN". do you mean /logs/system.log? I don't know where log to look...

Comment: Yes, system.log is the file you need to look at.

Comment: do u have any idea what can cause it? I don't know what to look at the log

Comment: Do you have any StatusLogger in the log file ?

Comment: no. but this insert statement takes me minutes... it makes sense? it is crashed after inserting about 3000 records of 10000....

Comment: Do you have jna http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installJnaTar.html?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Do you use ExecuteAsync ?**

```
session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
```

Asynchronism is good because Cassandra is able to handle parallel queries pretty well. But 10.000 queries may be too much to execute at a time.

If you do, try to use Execute. It would help Cassandra a lot.

**2. Do you use PreparedStatement ?**

```
var preparedStatement = session.Prepare("INSERT INTO table (key, column_name1, column_name2) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
var boundStatement = preparedStatement.Bind(key, value1, value2);
session.Execute(boundStatement);
```

Once again this is a good idea. But be carefull, preparing a statement has a cost. You must reuse already prepared statement as much as possible. Thus you will gain time.

If you do not, you should try, but use them properly.

**3. Do you have some very big blobs to insert ?**

Log the size of your data from the client side. You may also give us nodetool cfstats of your table.

If some values are bigger than 1Mo it could cause latency issue. Your network could be the problem. But I would rather think the Cassandra heap is the problem. When the Cassandra heap is filled with big values, GC are more frequent and longer. Is there any log of long GC (longer than 200 ms) in Cassandra system.log files ?

Comment: I use both of methods of Execute & ExecuteAsync & also PreparedStatement

Comment: Can you provide some code for us, so we can better see how you use the Datastax C# driver ?

Comment: something like:       for (long i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < genericEvents.Count; j++)
                {
                    GenericSessionEvent currEvent = genericEvents[j];
                    ser1.Serialize(stream1, currEvent.Child);
                    ser2.Serialize(stream2, currEvent.Element);
          

                    BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.Bind(i, j, ....stream1.GetBuffer(), stream2.GetBuffer());


                    await session.ExecuteAsync(boundStatement);         //NOT SURE FOR THE HEAP QUESTION U ASK

Comment: what I see in the logs that seems strange is: WARN [CompactionExecuter:13]... BigTableWriter.java:184 - Writing large partition ...tableNAme (107865330 bytes)

Comment: You execute asynchronously 10000 queries. That is a lot ! **Replace ExecuteAsync with Execute**. This is not optimized but **it will work**. Another solution is to increase wirte_request_timeout_in_ms in your cassandra.yaml files. But I dont recommend it to you.

Comment: i try execute also. same results. anyway I run "await" so It wait till return... want to mention also that 3000 iteration take about 5 minutes. this is a feature? I need to insert 6000 records in a sec...

Comment: How big are your values ? What is your schema and query ?

Comment: hi I've added more info in the question body. [added schema and query], do u mean what size of each row?

Comment: You should log the size of stream1.GetBuffer() and stream2.GetBuffer().

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting `10.000 x enericEvents.Count` rows in 10.000 partitions.

How much is **enericEvents.Count** ?

For a single *i*, all *enericEvents.Count* go to the same partition. A 107865330 bytes partition (> 100 Mo) is too big.

In the primary key the first column name is the partition key, the second is the clustering key. A solution is to not use any clustering key. You can do it this way :

```
primary key((id, seqid))
```

And you should use `Execute()` instead of `ExecuteAsync()`.

Comment: I dropped the clustering key & use sync operation (Execute).
it is still crashed...

both buffer size are 256 bytes.


after 2 minutes from the query it is crashed with after inserting 23000 records. [ enericEvents.Count  = 102].
the outer i variable of the outer loop value is 228

it cannot put all this data in several seconds by definition?
any help?

Comment: 23000 records in 2 min is not so bad. With some tuning of the cassandra.yaml, I am sure, Cassandra can do better. What version of cassandra are you using ? Nevertheless Timeout errors are not unusual in a ring life. It's a pity that your client application crash because of that. You should use a [retry policy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/1.0/common/drivers/reference/tuningPolicies_c.html) in your cluster object or implement your own. The idea is to catch the error, wait some time and retry, and next time you wait more.

Comment: I am using version 2.2.3. but how it can be so slow? if I use sqlserver I can insert a lot faster...what tuning are needed at the yaml?

Comment: Did you try any retry policy ?

Comment: Cassandra is fast when you use it with parrallelization. With your code when you use ExecuteAsync you are doing 1020000 insertions in parrallel. That is a lot too much. You should try with 10 or 20 thread workers that each inserts synchrnonously. And you have to use a retry policy too. Tuning the yaml depends on your infrastructure and is tricky. You will do it in a second phase.